# elasticsearch edge n-gram tokenizer: include symbols in the tokens

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using a custom tokenizer based on the Edge NGram tokenizer, and I would like to be able to search for strings like "sport+", i.e., I would like the special symbols, e.g., the + sign to be considered part of the token.

For example, we have documents with the following fields:

`"typeName": "LC 500h Sport+ CVT"`
or 
`"typeName": "LC 500h Sport CVT"`.

Executing a query with the following clause:

```
{
  "match": {
    "typeName": {
      "query": "sport+ cvt",
        "operator": "and"
    }
  }
}
```

fetches both documents. However, we would only like the document with `"typeName": "LC 500h Sport+ CVT"` to be returned in this case.

We have been using the following token_chars classes in the tokenizer settings: `digit`, `letter`, `punctuation`. I thought that adding `symbol` as a token_chars class and recreating the index would do the trick, but it has not helped.

**EDIT**:
Here is the analyzer definition in Nest syntax:

```cs
Settings(s => s
    .Analysis(_ =>
        _.Analyzers(a => a
                .Custom(
                    "vehicleanalyzer",
                    descriptor => descriptor
                        .Tokenizer(vehicleEdgeNgram)
                        .Filters("lowercase"))
                  .Standard("vehiclesearch",
                  descriptor => descriptor))
            .Tokenizers(descriptor => descriptor
                .EdgeNGram(
                    vehicleEdgeNgram,
                    tokenizerDescriptor =>
                        tokenizerDescriptor
                            .MinGram(1)
                            .MaxGram(10)
                            .TokenChars(
                                TokenChar.Digit,
                                TokenChar.Letter,
                                TokenChar.Punctuation,
                                TokenChar.Symbol)))))
```

Comment: Could you please share your analyzer definition?

Comment: @Lupanoide I added the analyzer definition in Nest syntax because this is how we had actually created it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As written in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html#_configuration_11) token_chars are:

> Character classes that should be included in a token. Elasticsearch
>   will split on characters that don’t belong to the classes specified.
>   Defaults to [] (keep all characters).

By default elasticsearch keep all the chars. You should use this option only if you want less classes of chars in your inverted index. So to resolve your problem you should simply remove the definition of token_chars: your tokenizer will keep all chars

Comment: Does that take care of whitespace, though? `whitespace` is also a valid token_chars class, but we do not want whitespace characters to be included in the tokens.

Comment: I tried recreating the index without specifying `token_chars`. The analyzer does handle whitespace correctly. However, the original problem remains: a query for `sport+ cvt` finds both `Sport+ CVT` and `Sport CVT`.

Comment: @Developer Ok. When you make a match query also the query is tokenized so elastic apply vehicleTokenization to sport+ and find sport. Maybe you should try with a match_phrase query

Comment: Unfortunately, same problem with `match_phrase` :( 
Also, `match_phrase` does not seem to meet some other requirements, e.g., it produces no results for a query like `lc cvt` because the words `LC` and `CVT` are not next to each other in the searched document.

Comment: You are right, in this case you should force to use another analyzer on query time - for example standard. It will tokenize on spaces . Then you should implement search_analyzer . please read here the part which explain edgengram and search_analyzer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html

Comment: please read also here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html